# PRNG MTRand mt.seed() not working as intended (?)

Tags: c++, random

In a simulation project where I need different PRNG with common random numbers (reproducability) I am using the Mersenne Twister implementation by Jasper Bedaux (http://www.bedaux.net/mtrand/). Now, the following loop should, in my understanding, produce a unique random number associated to the integer (i.e. the different instances should yield the same random numbers if initialised with the same seed):

```
#include <iostream>
#include "mtrand.cpp"

int main()
{
  MTRand tester_sh;
  MTRand tester_se;
  std::cout << std::fixed;
  std::cout << "This is a simple test program.\n";
  for (int sh = 1; sh < 3; sh++) {
    for (int se = 1; se < 3; se++) {   
      tester_sh.seed( sh );
      tester_se.seed( se );
      std::cout << "\n" << sh << "\t" << tester_sh() << "\t" << se << "\t" << tester_se() ;
    }
  }  
  return 0;
}
```

The output I do get, however is:

[image: Output test program]

Neither are the random numbers the same, nor does the "resetting" work for the individual generator. [edit: there is a pattern, of course, but I do not understand it / it is not as it should be]

As I am not a programmer, I am more than puzzled and do not know what I should do.

If important, I am compiling the model with **cygwin64\bin\x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe** and the options **-g  -Wall  -lm -std=gnu++14 -o %Name%.exe %Name%%Ext%**, using a current version of cygwin on windows 7, 64bit.

Any help is welcome!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, but why aren't you using the one implemented in the Standard Library: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random ?

Comment: Hi, thanks. I am using an IDE for ABMs called  [LSD](https://github.com/marcov64/Lsd) which only recently started using c++11/14. I will check if the c++11 MT is as easy to use as the Bedaux implementation (was/should be...). Still, this issue is rather miraculous to me and I'd like to understand it. Most times similar problems hunt me sometimes later...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because of some weird reason, `MTRand`'s state is `static`, so the state is shared between `MTRand` instances. A really bad decision.

Perhaps you can fix this with making the state non-static. Or just use a better implementation of MT. (btw, C++11 has `std::mersenne_twister_engine`)

Comment: Many thanks, that is something I could not have known, I guess. But I checked if I can switch to std c++11 MT implementation, as suggested also by @Bob__

Comment: Many thanks, that is something I could not have known, I guess. But I checked if I can switch to std c++11 MT implementation, as suggested also by @Bob,**and it worked.** (forgot that last part)

Answer (score 1):

Indeed the Mersenne Twister state vector is static in this port, as it is in many implementations, including the original implementation at http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/emt.html.

This is not for "some weird reason" and whether it is a "really bad decision" is up for discussion.

In the C++ standard implementation it is not static. The drawback of this is that it is quite easy to (accidentally) create multiple state vectors if you e.g. construct a new MT engine in some class. Every time a new MT engine is constructed, a new state vector is initialized and seeded. Probably most programmers will not realize this and may forget to properly seed each new instance, which may lead to problems with the quality of the pseudo random numbers depending on the implementation of the default seed (chance of repeating sequences), see e.g. http://www.pcg-random.org/posts/cpp-seeding-surprises.html.
In normal circumstances you should only use one generator engine, but the problem is programmers might not realize this.
Taking the next number from one properly seeded and used MT state vector will probably always be better then initialize and seed a separate state vector (which is also expensive). That is the reason for choosing one static (centralized) state vector: protecting users from accidentally creating multiple state vectors.
I agree however that this is not a good solution and is confusing when you are trying by purpose to create two separate state vectors, which is by the way only useful in very specific cases, like studying the behavior of the engine. When you are only looking for good quality random numbers it is probably only harmful to use more than 1 state vector.

Which solution is best depends on what you are trying to accomplish and how well programmers understand the implementation of the RNG.

Anyway, the lines

```
tester_sh.seed( sh );
tester_se.seed( se );
```

in the example are with this implementation equivalent to

```
tester_se.seed( se );
```

Edit: as geza and Sebastian point out in the comments below, the way the class is designed is not a good choice because it does not reflect the internal working.

Comment: "whether it is a "really bad decision" is up for discussion." - No, it really isn't. It's a class that from its interface pretends to have separate, independent instances, but shares all its state internally. That is the kind of design decision that I would describe with expletives.

Comment: @Jan: sorry, I hope I wasn't too offensive. Thanks for this explanation! But it still a bad decision in my opinion. The interface suggests that multiple MT's can be created, but actually cannot. "Which solution is best depends on what you are trying to accomplish and how well programmers understand the implementation of the RNG.": I agree with this. But, if someone is not skilled enough to use (seed) a random generator properly, they might not want to use MT either, and a "simple" PRNG will fit their need. If someone needs a very good PRNG, then they must learn it how to use it well.

Comment: Sebastian and geza, I admit in my post I was too focused on how the RNG is working. From this point of view I think it is a good decision to make the state vector shared. But I agree that from the point of view of the design of the C++ class the way it is implemented is not a good choice. It should be implemented in a way that reflects this, maybe as a Singleton class, although that might have some drawbacks.

Comment: Yes, a proper singleton interface would have been much better. Or at least a warning, that the state is shared. If `seed` is called on an instance, it is unexpected that a shared state is modified, instead of some property of that instance. Note, there's a long standing debate about (properly implemented) singletons' usefulness. I'm in the "dislike" camp. I dislike, when a class is inherently singleton. I much better like non-singleton classes, and if I just need one instance, then I'll just create one. Btw, using different PRNG's at the same time are not that rare as you might think...

Comment: ... There is a real need for them, when a program has different modules, and these modules should not interfere with each other at all. For a lot of people, current working is the confusing one. To be honest, I don't know any other random implementations (which are widely used), which works like this.

Comment: Having different instances can be very useful if one has a program with conceptually different aspects, where a PRNG is used. I needed it for a replication study in agent-based computational economics [Sample Size and Composition Effects: The Original El Farol Bar Model Revisited](https://www.researchgate.net/project/Analysis-of-Agent-based-Models/update/5a29f8de4cde266d58794065), where I wanted to understand the impact of two different, randomised initial conditions.